# jquery css() auto vendor prefixes not working?

Tags: jquery, css, vendor-prefix

I've read in several places that jquery 1.6 and onwards apply vendor prefixes automatically when using the css() method.
I'm using Jquery 1.11.1 and it appears to do no such thing.

If I call:

```
$(div).css({transform:"scale(2)"});
```

and check on Chrome developer tools' style inspector, it shows exactly that: "transform: scale(2);"
No vendor prefixes.

Why is this and should I add the various vendor prefixes myself?

Comment: I would have to look into exactly how this works a bit to know for sure, but have you tried it in a browser that requires the prefix?  It's possible if the non-prefixed is supported by the browser, the prefixed version is not added.

Comment: Chrome no more use vendor prefix for `transform`, so what are you expecting here, i don't get it? The question is, is that works on chrome or not? Seems easy to check

Comment: I tried it in firefox and internet explorer and neither added a prefix. I guess the newer versions no longer use the prefixes, not everyone will have the latest update though so it's still essential that I know it's working correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery will add the prefix for you, but only if the browser actually requires it. Chrome hasn't needed prefixes on transforms [for a while](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (as of version 36, to be precise), so jQuery doesn't bother.

This check is made in [line 6436](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d5ec2d8ac94a419ee47a39319c43ff9a7326b50/dist/jquery.js#L6436):

```
function vendorPropName( style, name ) {

    // shortcut for names that are not vendor prefixed
    if ( name in style ) {
        return name;
    }

    // ...
```